# Python Selenium problem with downloading file, preferences its not ok

Tags: python, selenium, csv, browser, download

I've got problem. On the page after clicked button download, the window os with"Open and exported documents" shows. On this window I see two radio buttons: 1. Open file 2. Save file. Default is checked "Open file" but I would like to check "Save file" and next click "OK"

I've got this code, but it doesn't work correctly.
Where is the mistake?

I've wiritten example_path in url. It's unreal path.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://example_path" 
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
driver_csv = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path= r"Desktop/programs/folder/geckodriver.exe")

profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())

profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', "application/csv, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values")
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "application/csv, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values")
profile.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/csv, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
# profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.tabs.warnOnClose", False)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: There is no mistake. Looks like you have not added the file type you are trying to download in the list you added to the preferences here.

Comment: I've try to download csv file. Is not text/csv or application/csv?

Comment: I don't know. I think there are several kinds of cvs files. I had similar issue  several months ago. let me see if I can find my final preferences settings

Comment: alright, I also try to find out a solution. :)

Comment: by the way, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 11 :)

Comment: Aha, OK... I use Python 3.8

Comment: I've checked by library "magic" what type of file I try to download. And I see that is text/plain

Comment: import magic

  mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
  print(mime.from_file("exported_documents.csv"))

Comment: but change "application/csv, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values" to"text/plain" have not hepled

Comment: if so I don't think I can help here.

Comment: reason: text/plain must be first on the list

Comment: So, I see you found the solution?

Comment: yes! You were right, problem based on list of the file types. "text/plain" must be first on the list

Comment: I don't think the order matters, but OK